# R Shiny SQL reactive query (selectInput not displaying)

Tags: sql, r, shiny

I would like to build a shiny app which will allow user to choose the table name from database, and their further plotting etc. I stuck at the point of retrieving the table names from database. I cannot use the `tableList` which i have created using `dbListTables(con,schema="K")` as a choice for the `selectInput` widget. I do not get any error or warning, widget just does not appear at all.

My code:

```
library(ROracle)
library(shiny)


server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {

    con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"),"xxx/K",username="user",password="pwd")
    tableList <- dbListTables(con,schema="K")
    output$out <- renderPrint(tableList) 

    df <- data.frame()
    quer <- paste("select * from K.", input$tabnames)
    df <- data.frame(dbGetQuery(con, quer))
    output$table <- renderTable({df})
    session$onSessionEnded(function() { dbDisconnect(con) })
  })

ui_panel <- 
  tabPanel("Test",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel( 
             ),
             mainPanel(
               selectInput("tabnames","tabnames", choices=as.list(tableList)),
               tableOutput("out"),
               tableOutput("table")
             )
           )
  )


ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Test",ui_panel))

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Thanks for any tipps

**[SOLVED]** the part for the `selectizeInput` i solved by placing it on the server side:

```
library(ROracle)
library(shiny)
library(DT)


server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {

    con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"),"xx/K",username="user",password="pwd")
    tableList <- dbListTables(con,schema="K")

    updateSelectizeInput(session, "tabnames", server = TRUE, choices = tableList)

    sqlOutput <- reactive({
      sqlInput <- paste("select * from K.",input$tabnames)
      dbGetQuery(con, sqlInput)
    })

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(sqlOutput(), server=TRUE, rownames=FALSE, filter="top", options=list(pageLength=10))

    session$onSessionEnded(function() { dbDisconnect(con) })
  })

ui_panel <- 
  tabPanel("Test",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel( 
             ),
             mainPanel(
               selectizeInput("tabnames",label = "server side", choices = NULL),
               tableOutput("out"),
               tableOutput("table")
             )
           )
  )


ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Test",ui_panel))

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

I additionally made the reactive SQL query.
Than i choosed the table from `selectizeInput` to display, **[NOT SOLVED]** however it shows me an error:

```
Error in .oci.GetQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
  ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

Than smthg has to be wrong with my SQL Query (Thanks for the tipps here!)
How its even possible if i choosed the table name from the `dbListTables`?
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get when run `dbListTables(con,schema="K")` outside `shiny`?

Comment: You need reactive `df <- data.frame(dbGetQuery(con, quer))` `df=reactive({dbGetQuery(con,paste0("select * from K.", input$tabnames) )})` and use `df()`  and delete:  `df <- data.frame()` and `quer <- paste("select * from K.", input$tabnames)`

Comment: also you need to render `output$sinput=renderUI({selectInput("tabnames","tabnames", choices=as.list(tableList))})` on server side and use as uioutput("sinput") on UI side

Comment: Thanks for the tipps!I solved the `selectizeInput` choices, however the sql query does not seem to work (I updated my question). `      sqlInput <- paste("select * from K.",input$tabnames)`, whereas K is a scheme. Thanks for additional solutions to the problem!

Comment: debug your code..error told you what you need "invalid table name", print your `sqlInput` before get it and look what bad

Comment: how it can be invalid table name, when the names are taken from the server...sorry but i have no idea how i can print `sqlInput` when its  reactive :(

Comment: add line `print(sqlInput)` before `dbGetQuery(con, sqlInput)`  and  comment `dbGetQuery(con, sqlInput)` and see into R what printed

Comment: it actually does not print anything ( this error `ORA-00903: invalid table name ` is displayed in shiny, but on the console i can see: `[1] "select * from k. AKT_KAW"`. Maybe the space between k. and AKT_KAW makes a problem?im going to try it out without space

Comment: `sqlInput <- paste("select * from kawasi.",input$tabnames,sep="")` did not work neither...

Comment: with `comment(dbGetQuery(con, sqlInput))` i got strange warning, which i didnt understand at all: `Warnung in min(d, na.rm = TRUE)
  kein nicht-fehlendes Argument für min; gebe Inf zurück
Warnung in max(d, na.rm = TRUE)
  kein nicht-fehlendes Argument für max; gebe -Inf zurück`

Comment: you know what `comment(` function do? in R code you can use # for comment line

Comment: no, i actually got very confused now..i know how to insert a comment line

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my **second question**! The problem was very small on the side of `ui`, instead of `dataTableOutput`, i had  `tableOutput`, so the `ui` should look like this:

```
ui_panel <- 
  tabPanel("Test",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel( 
             ),
             mainPanel(
               selectizeInput("tabnames",label = "server side", choices = NULL),
               tableOutput("out"),
               dataTableOutput("table")
             )
           )
  )
```

Thanks for all the help!